# need to edit xsd to get a specific format

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xsd, xsd2code

I'm using xsd2code and my xsd have this

```
<xs:element name="TransactionRequest">  
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Records">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>

          <xs:element name="RequestRecord" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="5">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Program" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="Key" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="Data" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>              
          </xs:element>

        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

What I want to achieve is this

```
[DataContractAttribute(Name = "TransactionRequest")]
public partial class TransactionRequest
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public RecordsType Records { get; set; }

    [CollectionDataContractAttribute(Name = "TransactionRequest.RecordsType", ItemName = "RequestRecord")]
    public class RecordsType : List<RequestRecord> { }
}

[DataContractAttribute(Name = "RequestRecord")]
public partial class RequestRecord
{
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Program { get; set; }
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

But what I get is this

```
[DataContractAttribute(Name = "TransactionRequest")]
public partial class TransactionRequest
{
    [XmlArrayItemAttribute("RequestRecord", IsNullable = false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public List<TransactionRequestRequestRecord> Records { get; set; }

    public TransactionRequest()
    {
        this.Records = new List<TransactionRequestRequestRecord>();
    }
}

[DataContractAttribute(Name = "TransactionRequestRequestRecord")]
public partial class TransactionRequestRequestRecord
{
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Program { get; set; }
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

What changes to the xsd do I need to make to get what I want?